# Objective C, on cell tap pass data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of cells within my UITableView that represent user messages.

When I tap the cell I need to go to a detail page of the message.

How can I link the message id to the cell so I can pass it to the detail page?

Comment: `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` should be called. Then you have the `indexPath`. Since you populated yourself the tableView, you should be able to retrieve the `id` from the array (if you used an array) you use. Then you can go to the details page with that `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click or tap table view cell, the table View Cell delegate method 
`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called.After that you can pass the message id to detailPage.

I have array.Inside the array I have lot of Id's.

I give you the example

ViewControlller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrSampData;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblVwSample;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController (){
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize arrSampData;
@synthesize tblVwSample;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     arrSampData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"55260",@"55261",@"55262",@"55263",@"55264",nil];
  }

//UITableView Data Source methods
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrSampData count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellid=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellid];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=arrSampData[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

//UITableView Delegate methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *strID =[arrSampData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   .......//Pass this id to your required view controller
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cell.tag to store ids

Comment: tag can store strings?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few way to solve your problem. One of them is using model for tableview management and custom cell, then using

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

other one is using cell tag. You can assign your detail message to the cell tag then show it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method again.

or you can use another view controller to show detail. for this you should perform segue and pass data between view controllers.